# OpenTok Nexmo outbound call won't work with SipProperty secure set true

Tags: java, opentok, tokbox, vonage

I'm integrating Nexmo in an application that uses [OpenTok React](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react) as the front-end and the [OpenTok Java SDK](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK) as the back-end.

When I set the `SipProperty secure` to `true` the call won't work.

When the `secure` property to false it will work.

Could someone explain this?

BTW i used an trial Nexmo account to test this.

Answer (score 1):

TokBox/Nexmo Developer Advocate here.

The `secure` property is a boolean flag that indicates whether the media must be transmitted encrypted (true) or not (false, the default).

The reason that the SIP dial does not work when setting `secure` to `true` is because at this time, Nexmo SIP does not support SRTP, you have to use RTP.

For more information, please check out the following resources:

- [OpenTok SIP Interconnect](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/sip/)
- [Nexmo SIP](https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/sip/overview)
- [SRTP](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/SRTP-Secure-Real-Time-Transport-Protocol-or-Secure-RTP)
- [RTP](https://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/Real-Time-Transport-Protocol)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response And also thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.